# How can I use a single Imageview to display 1 of several different icons

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I am new to this so any help or direction would be appreciated greatly!

How can I use a single Imageview to display 1 of several different icons in my drawables.

To give a specific example - When adding a new entry a user can select one of 15 different predetermined responses. Each has its own icon. Then later when viewing the entry, I need an ImageView showing the icon relating to the response selected.

I can do this by having 15 imageviews in my xml and changing the visibility but this seems a very messy and inefficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one ImageView, and use setImageDrawable method to switch images up to device state.
e.g.

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_image_resource))
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. Nice and simple and easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

Posting your code will be helpful to answer.

> When adding a new entry a user can select one of 15 different predetermined responses.

Hope you are getting response as integer(index)

```
private static final List<Integer> icon_list = Arrays.asList(R.drawable.option_1,R.drawable.option_2,...R.drawable.option_15);
view.findViewById(R.id.myIcon).setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, ICON_LIST.get(index)));
```

Incase if you are getting response as string, you can use either a hashmap to store key values or use switch case.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `bindingAdapter` and use databinding against your imageview to let the adapter do the work for you. Theres a nice example of working with imageviews [in the docs here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#kotlin)

So something like this (im using an enum as your response type)

```
@BindingAdapter("imageCustomDrawable")
fun setCustomDrawable(view: ImageView, responseType: EnumValue) {
  val drawableResId = when(responseType) {
    EnumValue.OK -> R.drawable.ok_drawable
    ...
  }

  view.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(drawableResId))
}
```

Your imageview xml would be

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/your_imageview"
  app:imageCustomDrawable="@{YOUR_RESPONSE_HERE}"/>
```